# Is it possible to modify http request timeout in Azure App Service - Django

Tags: django, azure

Currently this value is around 80 seconds. I tried modifying the timeout by multiple ways:

1. Modifying the web.config file.

`<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="600"/>
</system.web>`

2. Modifying `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` value in application settings in azure portal.
3. One more solution I got here: 
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/. I think this doesn't apply to Azure app service.

None of these are working. Is there a way we can modify timeout value?

Answer (score 0):

Change your config as per below for Python.
Set the desired `requestTimeout="00:04:00"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration>  
 <system.webServer>

  <handlers>
    <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*"
               modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>

  <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\Python27\python.exe" arguments="manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" requestTimeout="00:04:00" startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true">
    <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    </environmentVariables>
  </httpPlatform>

 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Read details https://prmadi.com/django-app-with-httpplatformhandler-in-azure-app-services-windows/

Comment: I tried the above solution, this too doesn't fix the problem. does the dynamic mechanism you are talking about applies to Azure app services as I didn't find any VM related information?

Comment: which connector you are using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list ?

Comment: I am using Django App service, which is a Python Http Rest api server. So while making a http call to this Django app I am getting timeout error.

Comment: I followed [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure)  so my config file is the one given in the link. In this config I tried the above code, it didn't work.